# Decrypting strings with arrays?

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm having trouble with one of my c++ assignments.
It's about decrypting a string of letters.

Here is a picture my teacher sketched up:

https://gyazo.com/33d90496958ef231dec7866e39ce1951

I must insert a string of letters using the command line. See the letters to the left on the picture i linked. They will be inserted in an array and it must this message: "DETTA ÄR KYPTERAT". It's in swedish, and it translates to "THIS IS ENCRYPTED".

The thing I'm having most trouble with is inserting the text into the multidimensional array using CIN.
It HAS to be a CIN in the beginning. Please answer in a simple and understandable as i'm still pretty novice at C++!

Comment: You mean like `std::cin >> data[x][y];`? Is the indexing the problem or is it something else?

Comment: Can you read in the entire string at once and process it later?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the details of your encryption algorithm, filling the 2d-array from standard input can be as follows:

```cpp
int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
char c; 
for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        cin.get(c);
        arr[i][j] = c;
    }
}
// just output for testing
for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I suppose `int` type will be good for your algorithm, but of course it is just example, and you can do any changes.